# add random elemnt from list to existing dataframe string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply

I have a dataframe. df['Skill']=python, sql, java. Now for each string I want to add random element (high, low, medium). For Eg: df['Skill']=python:high, sql:low, java:medium.

I have tried one code but it adds score['low', 'high', 'medium'] at the end of the string.

Can someone please suggest how can i do it.

```
score=['low','medium','high']
df[Skill']=df['Skill'].apply(lambda x:[x + ": " + "".join(w for w in random.choice(score))])
```

Output:

```
['python, java, sql: medium']
```

But i want is `python: low, java: high, sql: medium`

Comment: `lambda x: " ".join(w": "+s for w, s in zip(x.split(' '), random.choice(score, x.count(' '))))` you have to apply on each word by splitting

Comment: df['Skills']= d['Skills'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(w +": "+s for w, s in zip(x.split(', '), random.choice(score))))
output I get is  --- python: l , java: o, sql: w

Comment: Is there a value `sql: medium` in your 'Skill' column or `apply()`  is giving out this result?

Comment: I tried map and apply. both are giving me the same result

Comment: There is no [sql: medium] in the skill column only [sql] is present in the skill column output I get is using apply function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
df['Skill']= df['Skill'].apply(lambda x:','.join([y+': '+random.choice(score) for y in x.split(',')]))
```

Comment: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' this is the error I get

Comment: sorry i used variable name x inside the apply function, edited it, check now

Comment: Yes, I understood the error also understood the logic and I have resolved my problem Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
import random
skill = ['python','java', 'sql', 'html']
score=['low','medium','high']
select_score = list()
for i in range(len(skill)):
    select_score.append(random.choice(score))

select_score

freq_s = (dict(zip(skill, select_score)))
freq_s
```

output:

```
{'python': 'medium', 'java': 'low', 'sql': 'medium', 'html': 'low'}
```